# Powershell | Sort cmdlet sorting for specific variable

Tags: arrays, powershell, sorting

I want to sort an array.
The array contains several strings of text, numbers and variables.
The array should be sorted after the last variable (a number) in it.

the whole operation looks like this one:

```
function mainLoop {
    a
    b
    c
    d

    getTogether
}

function a {
    $Ranking = 4409
    $global:statement1 = "Lorem 903 ipsum dolor $Ranking"
}
function b {
    $Ranking = 1294
    $global:statement2 = "Lorem 186 ipsum dolor $Ranking"    
}
function c {
    $Ranking = 5502
    $global:statement3 = "Lorem 545 ipsum dolor $Ranking"
}
function d {
    $Ranking = 8192
    $global:statement4 = "Lorem 44 ipsum dolor $Ranking"
}
function getTogether {
    $array = @($statement1, "", $statement2, "", $statement3, "", $statement4)
    $array = $array | sort
    $array
    pause
}

mainLoop
```

So this one just sorts after the other existing numbers or even after the alphabet. in fact, i need to sort after the variable $Ranking.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Tip: `("a b c d" -Split "\s+")[-1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't make any sense (why are you using arrays and globals?), but here's how to sort on `$Ranking`

```
$Array = $Array | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression={[Int]($PSItem -split '\s')[-1]}}
```

Comment: Well I don't agree your point, it makes sense in fact that my code does what it is supposed to ;-) 
Of course there are maybe bether ways. I use the variables global because otherwise they don't provide the values in the last function..
However, your trick solved the issue so thank's a lot!

Comment: @Philae I'd suggest reading best-practices regarding global variables (in general), but I'm glad the solution worked for you.